# Login failed for an unknown reason: HTTP/1.0 500 handshakefailed

Tags: oracle, weblogic, jmx, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

Following steps I have performed :

1. Installed weblogic server (Oracle WebLogic Server 11g)and started. Now I'm able to see console page
2. Created Managed server and trying to start

   ./startManagedserver.sh server_name(Managed Server) admin_url

In the console I got below exception

> Login failed for an unknown reason: HTTP/1.0 500 handshakefailed

Even telnet for admin server is working fine. Please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The key detail you omitted is which protocol you use to connect to the admin server, but I assume you use `t3` (Weblogic default) protocol, so the `admin_url` is in format `t3://host:port`. T3 is not a HTTP based protocol, so this part of the response:

> HTTP/1.0 500 handshakefailed

does not come from a t3 server. My bet is that it comes form a HTTP proxy. This theory is also supported by `handshakefailed` reason phrase. The proxy expected HTTP Connect and received some t3 data, which it sees as a garbage.

Check the proxy configuration in your system and use for instance Wireshark to check, where the managed server really tries to connect.

Sometimes Java takes proxy configuration incorrectly from the system. For instance, it ignores *exclude localhost* on my Mac.

Comment: Hi Stepana, Thank you so much for your response. But  I have few more questions.                                                                                                              As I'm new weblogic. How can I check proxy configuration in my system as you mentioned(Check the proxy configuration in your system ).

Comment: To answer your question: I don't know how this works on other operating system, but Java takes proxy setting from network preferences on OS X (But uses them incorrectly as I said). 

My advice above was meant to push you in the right direction, it is impossible to give you any more concrete answer without knowing your environment such us: What OS are on? Where does the admin WLS run (localhost/remote)? Is there really a HTTP proxy between your machine (or the machine where you run the managed server if you run it remotely)? Do you really use T3 for the connection?

Comment: If I were you I would try to confirm the theory with the proxy first. I would use your favourite networking tool (like Wireshark) to find out where does the managed server really tries to connect. Only if you confirm the theory that it is not the admin server, but a proxy, then try to figure out where the configuration came from.